# How to open page by URL in Ionic 3 without ionic-native?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, deep-linking, ionic3

I know deep linking can be used, but I'm searching for something that opens a specific page when a specific URL is opened by the browser; without using ionic-native. Is there any way to do this?

Not only do I need it for the app, but it'd be useful during the development as well.

For example opening `http://localhost:8100/about-page` opens the about page.

Comment: `http://localhost:8100/#/about ` this can be done using lazy loading, but I don't think there is another way of invoking app without using any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into a third party like Branch? [Branch](http://branch.io) has an [ionic SDK](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking) that does that kind of standard deep linking by wrapping all the native standards like App Links, Universal Links, and URI schemes into one link.